# An efficient way to change this DOM structure in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

i want to reform the structure of a certain element. currently, it roughly resembles this structure.

```
<li>
    <a class="unitWrapper" href="location_url">
        stray textNode
        <img src="project1.jpg">
    </a>
    <a class="unitWrapper" href="another_url">
        link text
    </a>    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>                     
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p> 
</li>
```

and i want it to be built into the following structure using jQuery which in summary:

- gets the first link found in the list item
- unwrap it from it's contents
- use it to wrap everything in the list item
- if the link unwrapped contained text, wrap them in `<p>`

here's the new structure:

```
<li>
    <a href="location_url">
        <p>stray textNode</p>
        <img src="project1.jpg">
        <a class="unitWrapper" href="another_url">
            link text
        </a>    
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>                     
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </a>
</li>
```

and the jQuery code that i have now (which is kinda clunky) is this:

```
$('li').find('.unitWrapper').eq(0).each(function() { //get only the first link
    var $link = $(this);

    var $wrapperLink = $('<a/>');                   //the wrapper link
    var $strayWrapper = $('<p/>');                  //wrapper for stray textNodes like "link text" above

    $wrapperLink.attr('href', $link.attr('href'));  //copy link's location to the wrapper

    $link.contents()                     //get all the link's contents
        .unwrap()                        //unwrap it
        .parent()                        //go to the parent (<li>)
        .contents()                      //get all li's contents
        .wrapAll($wrapperLink)           //wrap it with the <a> created earlier 
        .filter(function(){                         
            return this.nodeType == 3;   //get all stray text nodes
        })
        .wrapAll($strayWrapper);         //wrap them with the <p> created earlier
});​
```

is there a better approach to doing this? and the only bearings i have is the `<li>` and the selector string `.unitWrapper`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way seems to be to append the rest of the content to the first a element:

```
$('li').each(function() {
    var first = $('a.unitWrapper', this).first();
    first.removeClass('unitWrapper')
         .append(first.siblings())
         .contents()
         .filter(function(){                         
             return this.nodeType == 3;   //get all stray text nodes
         })        
         .wrapAll("<p/>");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/wA3EJ/3/

Cant find a way to wrap the stray text nodes easier than this

Comment: perfect! i was so focused in unwrapping everything out, i never thought of appending it in. thanks!